# Material Icon theme not loading in visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, material-icons

[image]

Folder Icons and file icons are just little documents, not what is advertised, also it used to work. I tried using and older version, but did not work. Try your best to help, its fine if its impossible.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is restart Visual Studio Code and your compute. After that uninstall vs code completely and restart your computer, hope this helps the people that incountered this problem too.